# filter_var php question

Tags: php

I am making a quick little email script for a contact form and these variable aren't being set(`$firstName` and `$lastName`).

```
$firstName = filter_var($_POST['firstName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$lastName = filter_var($_POST['lastName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Note I am a beginner at php

Comment: Are you sure you have the values correct? What do you see if you `var_dump($_POST)` on the page?

Comment: did you ensure that the `$_POST[]` variables contain data?

Answer (score 7):

You're a beginner?  Well, hats off to you for using data validation from the get-go!

can you put this below those two lines and give us the output?

```
var_dump($firstName, $lastName, $_POST);
```

Comment: 'firstName' => string 'Dillon' (length=6)
  'lastName' => string 'Mulroy' (length=6)
  'email' => string 'test@thisisatest.com' (length=20)
  'contactOption' => string 'floralDesign' (length=12)
  'msg' => string 'test' (length=4)

Comment: So I guess they are being set I most likely have an error with my mail() function then.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does your mail function call look like?  Are you calling it with inline variables?  Are you aware that inline variables will be evaluated for double-quotes (`"`) but not single quotes (`'`)?

Comment: Hahah wowwwwwwww I forgot to add the $ sign in front of some variable when I was concatenating thanks for your guys help!

Comment: Hooray, the day is saved again!  Good luck man, keep on validatin' that data!

Answer (score -1):

As you have mention that you are beginner at php, I think you have not set form method. By default form method is **GET** and you are trying to fetch value using **POST** method. So either you change your form method to **POST** or set variable as below :

$firstName = filter_var($_GET['firstName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$lastName = filter_var($_GET['lastName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);